# How common are "How" + infinitive interrogative sentence structures?

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology, questions

In English (or at least varieties with which I am familiar), if you want to ask how to do something, you can't just ask "How to do {something}?"--that's interpreted as a headless relative, not a question. Instead, we have to use a finite verb with a dummy subject--"How do you do {whatever}?"

However, I have noticed that asking questions of the form "how" + infinitive, with no finite verb, seems to be a fairy common L2 error, and I know that that structure is, in fact, perfectly standard in, e.g., Russian.

So, how common is that structure? Is it an areal thing, or a language family thing, or just randomly distributed?

Comment: You can, though. Questions with _wh_-word + infinitive are stylistically marked and less common, but absolutely possible. More common with _what_ than with _how_, perhaps (and like with relatives, not possible at all with _why_), but hardly unheard of in either case. At any rate, the construction is completely standard in Romance languages as well, and _mutatis mutandis_ also in Chinese and Japanese. Possible with some words for ‘how’ in Irish, but not others (don’t know about the rest of Celtic, but I’d guess not possible in Welsh).

Comment: *Why stay home if ...* with a bare infinitive might be a better mark. I thought for a moment that German *wieso* "why" could reflect *\*to* despite late attestation and voice on the sibilant (in contrast to *was* "what" and *warum* "why; wherefore [are you, Romeo]"). A better comparison should be *wozu* "what for" (formerly *warzu*). *How be it?*, that's clearly subjunctive, by the way.

Comment: Cf. Grimm, DWB: [wozu](https://dwds.de/wb/dwb/wozu) "wozu **dienet** dieser unrat *ò* wo dienet dieser unrat zu? Kramer t.-ital. 2 (1702) 1377ᵃ;" (subjunctive preterite), "das ende, worzu wir **erschaffen** *ò* wo wir zu **erschaffen seynd** ebda." (elliptic infinitive participle, conjugated with auxilary), bold emphasis mine